# Stream Graph - Visualization in Python

Tags: python, visualization

https://rud.is/b/2015/03/12/streamgraph-htmlwidget-version-0-7-released-adds-support-for-markers-annotations/

The link above has a code snippet for beautiful visualization (Stream Graph) in R Language. Is there an equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stumbled upon this question while searching for one myself. I'll leave what I found in case someone else comes here:

- [pyechart](https://pyecharts.org/#/en-us/charts_base?id=themeriver)
- [altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_stacked_area_chart.html)
- [pystreamgraph](https://github.com/natronics/pystreamgraph/blob/master/Theme_River.test.png)
- [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stackplot_demo.html)

Comment: Out of the four options, 2 of them gave me a 404 error, another 1 of them is clearly underdeveloped, leaving matplotlib.

Comment: Updated the links